# Bind Dropdown in SSRS with all column name of Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to bind dropdown in SSRS with all column name of dataset.is this possible to select all column name from dataset in SSRS.please help me....because I am stuck in from last 10 days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a dataset out of those column names:

```
SELECT *
FROM [yourschema].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = [yourtablename]
```

Then just add a parameter, call it what you like.

Then, for available values, choose to get it from a dataset.